# Moving Wordpress website to another server

Tags: wordpress

A friend of mine asked me to move wordpress website from development server to production. I've copied all the files, backed up and restored database. After that I'd changed sitename and home values in database (_options table) to new domain  and it started. Though only home page is working fine. When I navigate to any other page it gives me 500 error. In error_log I got following errors:

> 1423021301: /home1/crankst1/public_html/fish-dev-site/ssv3_payload_extractor-r0Xkqq2xFD.php startup
>   [24-Feb-2015 19:16:59 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home1/crankst1/public_html/fish-dev-site/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_theme/include/classes/core/class-vc-sort.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home1/crankst1/public_html/fish-dev-site/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_theme/js_composer.php on line 168
>   [24-Feb-2015 19:16:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home1/crankst1/public_html/fish-dev-site/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_theme/include/classes/core/class-vc-sort.php' (include_path='.:/usr/php/54/usr/lib64:/usr/php/54/usr/share/pear') in /home1/crankst1/public_html/fish-dev-site/wp-content/plugins/js_composer_theme/js_composer.php on line 168

Paths that cause errors are related to development server and I can't find where to change them. I'm not very good with wordpress, so I suppose that solution should be very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is an issue with a plugin http://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431/comments?page=149 try to see if there are any hardcoded paths on the plugin dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also thought about Visual Composer plugin overriding path somehow but couldn't find where.  Though you helped me recheck everything and to find out that error_log showed very old errors (dated 24th of feb, as I moved website just yesterday). And real problem was in .htaccess.  Anyway, thanks for direction)

Answer (score 0):

Delete your .htaccess file then go to the permalinks page change to another permalink type save page then change back to permalink you had this will force wordpress to recreate the .htaccess file and it will allow all pages you have to show correctly on the site. :-)